# how to find maximum number M less than N in which some specific digit is not allowed to exist in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Recently I got a interview programming question about how to find maximum number M less than N, and some specific digit is not allowed to exist in M.

For example, N = 123, digit = 2，then it will output: 119

My ideas is to convert N to string first, and then find the first position of digit from left to right to make this digit decreased by 1. Then I set all the remaining digits in N to 9 to make this number maximized. Does some could point out some corner case which I ignored? and is there some good implementation in Java of this problem for reference?

Comment: Nice start, but it will fail if N doesn't contain digit, for example. Also, think about the case N = 113, digit = 2, here N-1 = 112, which contains 2.

Comment: `digit = 0` is a more tricky case and you cannot use 9 to maximize the number if `digit = 9`.

Comment: PS, the corner case you missed was you can't set to remaining digits to 9 if the banned digit is 9. Everything to 8 we go!

Answer (score 0):

> ... convert N to string first, and then find the first position of digit from left to right to make this digit decreased by 1.

That seems difficult. How would you "find the position to make a digit decreased"?

Why not go with a more brute-force approach: keep the number as a number, decrease it one by one, convert to string to find if the digit exists, for example:

```
public int getMaxN(int N, char digit) {
    for (int i = N; i > 0; --i) {
        if (Integer.toString(i).indexOf(digit) == -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

@Test
public void testGetMaxN() {
    assertEquals(119, getMaxN(123, '2'));
    assertEquals(122, getMaxN(123, '3'));
    assertEquals(99, getMaxN(123, '1'));
}

@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void testNoSuchElement() {
    getMaxN(0, '0');
}
```

Probably a more intelligent and efficient method exists.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 3. Still O(n) but due to the special 0 case needing to cascade back up:

```
static int banDigit(int number, int digit) {
    int length = (Integer.toString(number)).length();
    int result = 0;
    boolean foundDigit = false;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!foundDigit) {
            int currentDigit = (int) number / ((int) Math.pow(10, i));
            number = number % (int) Math.pow(10, i);
            if (currentDigit == digit) {
                //if nonzero digit banned, we can just decrement and purge 9 or 8 to right
                if (digit > 0) {
                    currentDigit--;
                } else {
                    // we have to subtract one from the previous 
                    result = result - (int) Math.pow(10, i);
                    //then we have to check if doing that caused a bunch of ones prior
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                        if ((int) (result % (int) Math.pow(10, j + 1)) / (int) Math.pow(10, j) == 0) {
                            result = result - (int) Math.pow(10, j);
                        }
                    }
                }
                foundDigit = true;
            }
            result += currentDigit * Math.pow(10, i);
        } else if (digit == 9) {
            result += 8 * Math.pow(10, i);
        } else {
            result += 9 * Math.pow(10, i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Works in many case but I found a bug for N = 11020, digit = 0. The code outputs -99999.

Comment: Good catch! I actually improved the formula quite a bit, missed an easy solution. Let me know how this one looks XD

Comment: I also found a bug, please try: N = 211000, digit = 0 The output is 209999 which still contains 0 !

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it has to be recursive? Oh, wait, I think I know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The trick I used is to find the correct number to subtract from the original number and max out the rest of the number. This is usually just a number with a 1 in the first bad digit place, but it is a bit more tricky if the banned digit it 0 since it can produce more 0's when the subtraction carries over. This happens when there is a string of digits like 1110 with 1's preceding the 0's. My program keeps track of these in this O(n) time solution where n is the number of digits.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RemoveDigits {

  public static BigInteger removeDigits(BigInteger number, int banned) {
    char[] digits = number.toString().toCharArray(); // digits of the number
    char[] subtractChars = null; // array used to initialize BigInteger to subtract from the bad digit
    char maxDigit = banned == 9 ? '8' : '9'; // digit to fill rest of the number with
    int badCarryIndex = -1; // if banned == 0 keep track of the carry possibility
    int badDigitIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      if (banned == 0 && digits[i] == '1') { // keep track of first character affected by carry
        if (badCarryIndex < 0) {
          badCarryIndex = i;
        }
      } else if (Character.digit(digits[i], 10) == banned) {
        badDigitIndex = i;
        if (badCarryIndex != 0) { // calculate the real first character affected by carry
          badCarryIndex--;
        }
        subtractChars = badCarryIndex < 0 ? new char[digits.length - badDigitIndex] : new char[digits.length - badCarryIndex - 1];
        subtractChars[0] = '1';
        break;
      } else { // reset if found a good character
        badCarryIndex = -1;
      }
    }
    if (badDigitIndex >= 0) {
      // fill the rest of the digits with maxDigit
      Arrays.fill(digits, badDigitIndex + 1, digits.length, maxDigit);
      // build subtractChars
      if (badCarryIndex >= 0) {
        // banned == 0, have to worry about carry producing 0's
        Arrays.fill(subtractChars, 1, badDigitIndex - badCarryIndex, '1');
        Arrays.fill(subtractChars, badDigitIndex - badCarryIndex, subtractChars.length, '0');
      } else {
        Arrays.fill(subtractChars, 1, subtractChars.length, '0');
      }
      BigInteger maxedNumber = new BigInteger(new String(digits));
      BigInteger subtractNumber = new BigInteger(new String(subtractChars));
      return maxedNumber.subtract(subtractNumber);
    }
    return number; // no bad digits in original number
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("20"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("210"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("123"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("123"), 2));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("1000"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("1000"), 1));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("1111020"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("2011020"), 0));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("80000009"), 9));
    System.out.println(removeDigits(new BigInteger("80937921"), 9));
  }
}
```

It prints:

> 19
>   199
>   123
>   119
>   999
>   999
>   999999
>   999999
>   80000008
>   80888888

Edit: fixed corner case pointed out by JoJo.

Comment: I fixed it with the code: if (badCarryIndex != 0) {badCarryIndex--;}

Answer (score -1):

I think it works, please tell me if you see any case not well handled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N     = 100211020;
    int digit = 0;

    int m;
    for (m = 9 ; m > 0 && m == digit; m--);

    String sres;
    String s   = N + "";
    int length = s.length();
    int i      = s.indexOf(digit + "");

    if (i < 0)
        sres = s;
    else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (digit != 0) {
            for (int j=0 ; j<i ; j++) sb.append(s.charAt(j));
            sb.append(digit - 1);
            for (int j=i + 1 ; j<length ; j++) sb.append(m);
        } else {
            if (s.charAt(0) != '1')
                sb.append(mod10(s.charAt(0) - '0' - 1));
            for (int j=1 ; j<length ; j++) sb.append(9);            
        }
        sres = sb.toString();
    }
    System.out.println(sres);
}

public static int mod10(int n) {
    int res = n % 10;
    return res < 0 ? res + 10 : res;
}
```

**EDIT :**

I finally decided to use strings to handle the case of `digit = 0`, which was quite complicated with my first approach.

Comment: I've found that `Integer.toString(i)` is faster than using `StringBuilder` and appending each digit from `i`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I'm not sure to understand how I should use this observation to improve my code with minor changes, could you give me a hint ?